# Better way to sum total of all children models' value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to do the following and it is working but I'm sure there has to be a better way of doing this. I'd really appreciate your input. Thanks a lot.

```
public static function calculateStorageUsage(){
    $kb = 0;

    $properties = Auth::user()->landlord_profile_auto->properties()->with('images')->get();
    foreach($properties as $property){
        foreach($property->images as $image){
            $kb += $image->size_kb;
        }
    }
    return $kb;
}
```

I'm trying to calculate the total storage used by all the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since relationships return a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) by default, the following should work:

```
public static function calculateStorageUsage()
{
    $properties = Auth::user()
        ->landlord_profile_auto
        ->properties()
        ->with('images')
        ->get();

    return $properties->images->sum('size_kb');
}
```